# Android: Start an activity from a Runnable activity (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I have a Runnable `GameView` that draw some animation, and it is created and used in `NewGame` activity. And `NewGame` starts another activity called `PetInfo` onClick of a Button on the view. However whenever I start `PetInfo`, I get the following errors:

> 04-06 19:13:30.025 23272-23272/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>
> 04-06 19:13:30.211 23272-23312/com.example.xuan.tictactoe D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
>
> 04-06 19:13:30.219 23272-23272/com.example.xuan.tictactoe D/Atlas: Validating map...
>
> 04-06 19:13:30.245 23272-23312/com.example.xuan.tictactoe I/Adreno-EGL: : QUALCOMM Build: 01/14/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
>
> 04-06 19:13:30.246 23272-23312/com.example.xuan.tictactoe I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>
> 04-06 19:13:30.267 23272-23312/com.example.xuan.tictactoe D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
>
> 04-06 19:14:40.950 23272-23272/com.example.xuan.tictactoe D/test: onCreate
>
> 04-06 19:14:40.956 23272-23272/com.example.xuan.tictactoe D/test: onCreate after set view
>
> 04-06 19:14:41.161 23272-24500/com.example.xuan.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8231
>
> > Process: com.example.xuan.tictactoe, PID: 23272
> >
> > **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference**
> >
> > > at com.example.xuan.tictactoe.GameView.draw(GameView.java:135)
> > >
> > > at com.example.xuan.tictactoe.GameView.run(GameView.java:100)
> > >
> > > at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

**`NewGame`** activity

```
public class NewGame extends Activity {
GameView game_view;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game_view = new GameView(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
  }


  // This method executes when the player starts the game
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Tell the gameView resume method to execute
    game_view.resume();
  }

  // This method executes when the player quits the game
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Tell the gameView pause method to execute
    game_view.pause();
  }

  // Start new activity
  public void createInfo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PetInfo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

**`GameView.java`**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
Thread game_thread = null;

// SurfaceHolder for Paint and Canvas in a thread
SurfaceHolder the_holder;

// Canvas and Paint objects
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
Bitmap dragon;

volatile boolean is_running;

long fps; // tracks the game frame rate
private long time_this_frame; // calculate the fps
float x_position = 0;  // start position
float y_position = 0;
long frame_ticker = 0l;

// New variables for spritesheet
private int frame_count = 10;  // How many frames are there on the sprite sheet?
private int sprite_width = 600;
private int sprite_height = 450;
private int current_frame = 0; // Start at the first frame - where else?

// A rectangle to define an area of the sprite sheet that represents 1 frame
private Rect frame_to_draw = new Rect(0, 0, sprite_width, sprite_height);

// A rect that defines an area of the screen on which to draw
RectF where_to_draw = new RectF(x_position, 0, x_position + sprite_width, sprite_height);

// Constructor methods
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    // Initialize ourHolder and paint objects
    the_holder = getHolder();
    the_holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            resume();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }
    });

    paint = new Paint();

    // Load dragon from .png file
    dragon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.gd10_spritesheet);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (is_running) {
        // Capture the current time in milliseconds in startFrameTime
        long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        update();  // Update the frame
        draw(); // Draw the frame

        // Calculate the fps this frame to time animations.
        time_this_frame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
        if (time_this_frame >= 1) {
            fps = 5000 / time_this_frame;
        }
    }
}

// Everything that needs to be updated goes in here
// In later projects we will have dozens (arrays) of objects.
// We will also do other things like collision detection.
public void update() {
    long game_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (game_time > (frame_ticker + fps)) {
        frame_ticker = game_time;

        current_frame++;
        if (current_frame >= frame_count) {
            current_frame = 0;
        }
    }

    frame_to_draw.left = current_frame * sprite_width;
    frame_to_draw.right = frame_to_draw.left + sprite_width;
}

// Draw the newly updated scene
public void draw() {
    // Make sure our drawing surface is valid or we crash
    if (the_holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

        canvas = the_holder.lockCanvas(); // Lock the canvas ready to draw
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 144, 195, 212)); // Draw the background color
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 249, 129, 0)); // Choose the brush color for drawing

        x_position = (float) (this.getWidth()/2.0 - frame_to_draw.width()/2.0);
        y_position = (float) (this.getHeight()/4.0 - frame_to_draw.height()/2.0);

        where_to_draw.set((int) x_position,
                (int) y_position,
                (int) x_position + sprite_width,
                (int) y_position + sprite_height);

        canvas.drawBitmap(dragon,
                frame_to_draw,
                where_to_draw, paint);

        the_holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); // Draw everything to the screen
    }
}

// If activity is paused/stopped shutdown our thread.
public void pause() {
    is_running = false;
    try {
        game_thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", "joining thread");
    }
    game_thread = null;

}

// If activity is started then start our thread.
public void resume() {
    is_running = true;
    game_thread = new Thread(this);
    game_thread.start();
}
}
```

**`activity_new_game.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.xuan.tictactoe.NewGame">

<com.example.xuan.tictactoe.GameView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="OK"
    android:onClick="createInfo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Funny thing is that I put some Log in onCreate of `PetInfo` and the Log runs, that means `PetInfo` activity is created but for some reasons it throws errors on the thread of the previous activity (which is `NewGame`'s `GameView`).

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`Runnable` = different/background thread, not main thread. This makes code done inside of `Runnable` be able to take a long time without locking the main/UI thread.

However, this also means you cannot update the main/UI thread from a different/background thread. You can only update the UI thread once the `Runnable` action has been completed, and you're out of the `Runnable` block.

Comment: I think with my code, the thread completes it tasks and joins before the new activity starts. And the new activity actually runs but then the app throws errors on the thread. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: so you gave me a -1 for something you think it does?

Comment: I didn't give you a -1.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Somebody else downvoted you. The OP doesn't have enough rep to downvote.